# Python: Error importing gtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Im using LinuxMint and Python 2.7.3 on it. 
I have tried to import gtk installing and reinstalling all the dependencies, but i'm always getting:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: 
Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
from gtk import _gtk
```

I have found on other threads and answers that might be a bug, and others a conflict with pygtk. (i have tried to import gtk without pygtk and i get the same error).

Is anyone getting something similar or know how to fix it ?

Comment: Please name the exact import statement. Are you using `from gtk import _gtk` as appeared in your error message? I've never seen that before and wondered why this works. Also specify if you want to do GTK 2 or 3.

Comment: No, the statement is just import gtk:
import gst, pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

Comment: I installed via http://sourceforge.net/projects/macpkg/files/PyGTK/2.24.0/PyGTK.pkg/download and when I do "import gtk" in python, I get a similar error: /opt/gtk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gio/__init__.py:28: Warning: gboolean g_str_has_prefix(const gchar *, const gchar *): assertion `str != NULL' failed
  import unix
Segmentation fault: 11